# Making an automatic night light

Tags: transistors, light

I'm a total beginner so I'm sorry for stupid question(s).

I want to design a circuit and I'm stuck. Here's the description:

Photosensor outputs 0V until the ambient light decreases below certain level, after which it outputs 5V. With that signal, I want to turn on 24 V light bulb (draws 250 mA).

I have a few questions:

- I definitely need 24 V battery or 24 V DC voltage source in my circuit right? I can't do much with just 5V?
- In LTspice there's no photosensor. Can I use 5 V DC voltage source instead? (As far I understand, photosensor acts as switch, right?)
- Do I use MOSFET or BJT?

If you check the picture, I tried to do it like this: The 5 V DC on left side activates the MOSFET. I need resistance of 93 ohm (since 24-0,7=23,3 and I want 250 mA). But it's not working. I think that left DC voltage is destroying my circuit.

Any help would be appreciated.

[image: schematic]

Answer (score 2):

*I want to design a circuit and I'm stuck.*

Yeah well, like many, many "aspiring circuit designers" have experienced before you, it is **nearly impossible** to do circuit design without knowing how certain circuits are build up. Yes, a MOSFET can act as a switch and yes a resistor can limit a current but knowing that is not enough.

For example, for an NMOS to act as a switch its gate-source voltage needs to be switched between for example 0 V (off) and 5 V (on). In your circuit the 5 V for on/off sits between the gate and something that is not the source.

I strongly advise you to search the internet and look for circuits which do the same. "NMOS switch circuit" should be a good start. Use the "images" tab to see pictures of schematics. Not how many are similar. Then build something similar in LTspice and experiment with it.

To learn how to properly design circuits I would recommend **looking** at circuits a lot and figure out what makes them tick. Re-build circuits in a simulator and make **small modifications** then **think** what effect that will have and then **confirm that** using the simulator. If you like that and gain more experience with that you can become an excellent circuit designer.

If you just want the night light function and don't aspire a career in electronics ( :-( but your choice) then **don't** try to design a circuit yourself, it will end in tears. Just browse the internet for similar projects and **copy that**. Circuit design isn't something you can learn quickly to make a circuit you suddenly need. The hard work has been done already by others so just copy what they did.

Comment: Thanks my friend, for all the advices. I did some research on NMOS switch circuit. I wasnt that far from answer. I removed the diode and connected 5V DC only to gate and grounded it. I just wired it up before like im an autistic mongloid. Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

It's not at all clear what you mean by "photosensor". If you mean a photoresistor then your understanding is incorrect. The photoresistor does not "put out" any voltage and it does not act like a switch, it just acts as a resistor where the resistance decreases significantly when exposed to light. If that's not the kind of sensor you plan to use then you should provide a link to the data sheet of the sensor.

The photoresistor should be connected between the NMOS gate and ground, with another resistor between the gate and +24V. When light shines on the photoresistor its resistance goes down and the NMOS gave voltage rises with respect to ground, increasing the drain current. The tricky part will be finding a good value for the "other resistor" that causes the light to switch on and off as desired.

You don't need the diode at all.

Comment: I meant photoresistor yes and i knew everything of that yeah. Problem was LTspice doesnt have photoresistor, so insted of using photoresistor and voltage source, i just used voltage source. But it works the same. When DC voltage is 0, nothing happens, when 5V, circuit works. Yeah no idea, what my thought proces what with that diode. I removed it, rewired and its working now.

Answer (score -1):

Your design won't work even with Photo-R on gate to gnd with pullup of ~100K ~ 1M since it linear and uses an 8 W bulb has 10% of hot resistance when cold. so the FET  will fry when dim.  You need high gain and hysteresis.
Vgs(th) are often 2~4V and need 3x this to be low R.

So use a 12 or 24V stripLED instead of diode +R and use a circuit with hysteresis since you dont have enough gain to make a switch and at half power the FET will try to get as hot as the bulb! ( equal power)

You can find a better design than this anywhere.  (-0.5 for poor research)